# fmod issue undefined reference

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, modulus

Hey so i am trying to use fmod as i have to take the modulus of two doubles. My make file does the following.

```
gcc -static -lm vm_main.c vm_options.c vm_menu.c vm_utility.c -o main
```

so the -lm tag should include the math header right?

i have included math.h in my files.

```
#include "vm_menu.h"
#include "vm_type.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

im a little confused as to why this is occurring... :/

Comment: You need to put the libraries you link with *after* the object/source files on the command line.

Comment: Sweet, do you have any idea why this error continues to occur within eclipse but only generates warning within terminal?

Comment: The linking stage should result in an error in both cases which should cause `make` to exit immediately with an error.

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought. hmmm. Ill restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

> so the -lm tag should include the math header right?

No, it tells the linker to link to libm, the math library. That's a library, not a header. But [the order of linker options is important](http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html) so it needs to come after the files that use it.